# Differentials in spectral sequences and Massey products

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, cohomology, spectral-sequences, differential-graded-algebras

Consider a multiplicative spectral sequence such as the cohomological Serre spectral. It is known that differentials will satisfy a Leibniz rule. Is there a clean statement involving differentials and Massey products. For example, if $d^{r_1}(x_1)d^{r_2}(x_2)=0$ and $d^{r_2}(x_2)d^{r_3}(x_3)=0$, then is some differential equal to the Massey product of $d^{r_1}(x_1), d^{r_2}(x_2)$ and $d^{r_3}(x_3)$ under certain conditions? Is there a reference that talks about this?

Comment: Unless r1=r2=r3, how do you even make sense of the multiplication?